# This sql statement is not a query Import Wizard

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

I am trying to import data from an excel file to one of my table so I am using the SQL server import and export wizard in the management studio and providing a source query. When I click parse after entering below query, I get This sql statement is not a query.

```
select 
    u.UserID, m.IMManagementPlatformID, s.Username
from 
    ([Sheet1$] s 
inner join 
    dbo.wmcTBLUsers u on u.Firstname = s.Firstname 
                      and u.Lastname = s.Lastname) 
inner join 
    IMManagementPlatform m on m.IMManagementPlatformName = s.IMManagementPlatformName 
where 
    u.IsActive = 1 
    and u.Firstname <> 'First' 
    and u.Lastname <> 'Last'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is from Microsoft Office Access Database Engine.

It parses the query that accesses only Excel file, not SQL Server database,
so you can use only other Excel sheets in your query